# Problemas com Threads no Windows Form

Tags: c#, thread, multithreading, asynctask, threadpool

estou tentando implementar `Threads` em meu algoritmo, porem ao adicionar e executar o meu software o `Windows Form` dele trava e não executa nenhuma ação, conseguem ver algo de errado no código abaixo?
Sei que existe o `Async/Await` para ser usado com a `task`, porém é possível usar Threads como usei, no `Windows Form`? Se não, qual seria a melhor forma de adicionar um pool de `task` que "tiraria" pelo menos 90% do meu processador para execução do Algoritmo?

Desde já agradeço!

```
    GeneticAlgorithm AG = new GeneticAlgorithm();
    List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

    for (i = iTemp; i < evolucoes; i++)
    {
        Thread thread_corrente = new Thread(() =>
        {
            #region
            iTemp++;

            lbEvolucoes.Text = i.ToString();
            lbEvolucoes.Refresh();

            pop = AG.executeGA(pop);

            if (twoOptCheck.Checked)
            {
                if (i == evolucoes - 1)
                    Utils.TwoOpt(pop.getBest());
            }
            pop.getBest().CalcFitness();

            //Limpar o grafico
            zedMedia.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();
            zedMedia.GraphPane.GraphObjList.Clear();

            double mediaPop = pop.getMediaPop();
            mediaPopulacao.Add(i, mediaPop);

            double bestFitness = pop.getBest().getFitness();

            lbMenorDistancia.Text = bestFitness.ToString("0.0");
            lbMenorDistancia.Refresh();

            LineItem media = paneMedia.AddCurve("Média", mediaPopulacao, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);

            //Print linhas a cada 6 evolucoes
            if (i % 6 == 0 && bestFitness < bestAux)
            {
                bestAux = bestFitness;
                g.Clear(Color.White);
                plotLines(pop, Color.Blue);
                plotPoints();
            }

            zedMedia.AxisChange();
            zedMedia.Invalidate();
            zedMedia.Refresh();
            #endregion
        });

        thread_corrente.Start();
        threads.Add(thread_corrente);
        if (threads.Count >= 10)
        {
            while (!ThreadsTerminaramDeProcesssar(threads))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }

            threads.Clear();
        }
    }

    g.Clear(Color.White);
    plotLines(pop, Color.Blue);
    plotPoints();

    btnExecutar.Enabled = true;
}
```

Verifica se a Thread já processou:

```
   private bool ThreadsTerminaramDeProcesssar(List<Thread> threads)
    {
        bool TodosTerminaramDeProcessar = true;

        foreach (Thread thread in threads)
        {
            //true => não terminou seu processamento.
            //false => terminou seu processamento.
            if (thread.IsAlive)
                TodosTerminaramDeProcessar = false;
        }

        return TodosTerminaramDeProcessar;
    }
```

Comment: Poder usar *thread* direto, pode, mas não deve. O motivo principal é porque é muito difícil fazer certo. Usando `Task` é difícil, mas a maioria dos erros não serão cometidos. Debugar *thread* é provavelmente a coisa mais complicada que existe na computação. E é isso que está pedindo. Eu não farei por você, ainda que o problema possa ser simples neste caso, nem quero perder tempo. É provável que tenha até uma forma melhor de fazer todo o código. Eu já vejo coisas esquisitas aí, parece que está querendo recriar o `Task` já faz por você.

Comment: Toda vez que vejo um `Thread.Sleep()` eu tenho quase certeza que tem algo errado no código mesmo. Este código é confuso demais, a solução real é fazer de um jeito melhor, não parece ser um problema pontual que possamos ajudar.